# Is eating fish eggs the same as killing?

Tags: five-precepts

Is eating fish eggs that we normally find in sushi dishes the same as kiling? Is there any life terminated when we eat them?

Answer (score 1):

the biggest problem is that the fish species for which there is a caviar market are becoming extinct because they cannot reproduce. Many countries are trying to ban the import of the eggs to protect the species.

there are many fish for which the eggs are sold, for this question there are two categories:

1) the eggs are harvested from inside the mother fish. She is pulled out of the water, then to retrieve the eggs her body is sliced from tail to mouth to access the eggs, usually on the boat, often while she is still alive. The eggs may have been fertilized inside her (depending on species).

2) the fish lays the eggs, which are fertilized (either inside her or in the water), and then they are harvested.

either way there is death.

Answer (score 0):

This is a question we cant draw a margin. So I will not give a direct answer. But if you can search, try to find these two stories.
1. Story of God "Sakra" helping to one of his wives who was born as a crane.
2. Story of the couple who organized an almsgiving laid a carpet and wished if Lord Buddha walked on it they will have a baby.

(These two stories will help you to find an answer at least to your satisfaction)

Answer (score 0):

I suppose the "life is terminated" earlier: when the eggs are taken from the fish (prematurely), or when the eggs are refrigerated (I think that eggs, fish eggs too, need warmth to keep growing).

This may be more of a question about biology than Buddhism though ... so perhaps ask it on [Biology.SE](https://biology.stackexchange.com/) or [Vegetarianism.SE](https://vegetarianism.stackexchange.com/) ... I don't know that there's any answer that's specific to Buddhism.